# При обновлении state react не перерисовывает приложение

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

уважаемые форумчане.

Я новичек в React и у меня возникла проблема, которую я не могу решить вот уже 3 дня.

Дело в том, что при изменении состояния, будь то добавление или удаление заметки, state изменяется, но приложение не перерисовывается, а в случае с добавлением, функция в onClick срабатывает только со второго раза, но работает и меняет state(убедился через console.log(this.state.todos)).

Прилагаю свой код, буду признателен за помощь.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Menu from "./Menu/Menu";
import SearchPanel from "./SearchPanel/SearchPanel";
import HorizontalMenu from "./HorizontalMenu/HorizontalMenu";
import NoteBoard from "./NoteBoard/NoteBoard";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          id: "fghsf",
          completed: false,
          title: "Hello World",
          text:
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took"
        },
        {
          id: "adfgd",
          completed: false,
          title: "toggle JavaScript",
          text:
            "The toggle() method of the DOMTokenList interface removes a given token from the list and returns false. If token doesn't exist it's added and the function returns true."
        },
        {
          id: "asdsa",
          completed: false,
          title: "Fetch API",
          text:
            "The Fetch API provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and responses. It also provides a global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network."
        },
        {
          id: "12312sasda",
          completed: false,
          title: "Single-page application (SPA)",
          text:
            "A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or website that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current web page with new data from the web server, instead of the default method of the browser loading entire new pages."
        }
      ],
      modal: false,
      randomId: `f${(~~(Math.random() * 1e8)).toString(16)}`
    };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem(addTitle, addText) {

    const newItem = {
      id: this.state.randomId,
      completed: false,
      title: addTitle,
      text: addText
    };

    this.setState(({ todos }) => {
      const newArr = [...todos, newItem];
      return {
        todos: newArr
      };
    });
    console.log(this.state.todos);
  }

  deleteItem(id) {
    this.setState(({ todos }) => {

      const index = todos.findIndex(elem => elem.id === id);

      const before = todos.slice(0, index);
      const after = todos.slice(index + 1); 

      const newArr = [...before, ...after];

      return {
        todos: newArr
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos, modal } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.todos);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <Menu />
          <div className="notes-block-container">
            <SearchPanel />
            <HorizontalMenu modal={modal} addItem={this.addItem} />
            <NoteBoard todos={todos} onDelete={this.deleteItem} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import NoteItem from "../NoteItem/NoteItem";

import "./NoteBoard.css";

export default class NoteBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: this.props.todos
    };
  }

  piz(da) {
    console.log(da);
  }
  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    const { onDelete } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="noteBoard-container">
          {todos.map(todo => {
            return (
              <NoteItem
                todo={todo}
                key={todo.id}
                onDelete={() => onDelete(todo.id)}
                id={todo.id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./NoteItem.css";
import pin from "./NoteItemIcons/pin.svg";

export default class NoteItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todo, onDelete } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="note-item">
          <div className="pin">
            <img src={pin} />
          </div>
          <div className="functions">
            <div className="functions1">
              <div className="delete" onClick={onDelete} />
              <div className="done" />
              <div className="change" />
            </div>
            <div className="functions2">
              <div className="settings" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="note-title">{todo.title}</div>
          <div className="note-text-container">
            <p className="note-text">{todo.text}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewNoteModal from "../NewNoteModal/NewNoteModal";

import "./HorizontalMenu.css";
import completed from "./HorizontalMenuIcons/completed.svg";
import newNote from "./HorizontalMenuIcons/newNote.svg";
import recentlyDeleted from "./HorizontalMenuIcons/recentlyDeleted.svg";
import sort from "./HorizontalMenuIcons/sort.svg";

export default class HorizontalMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalOpened: false
    };
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpened: true
    });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpened: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="horison-menu">
          <div className="horison-menu-first-block">
            <div className="new-note" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>
              <img src={newNote} alt="new note image" />
              <p className="hor-menu-item-text">new note</p>
            </div>
            <div className="completed">
              <img src={completed} alt="completed image" />
              <p className="hor-menu-item-text">completed</p>
            </div>
            <div className="recently-deleted">
              <img src={recentlyDeleted} alt="recently deleted image" />
              <p className="hor-menu-item-text">Recently deleted</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="horison-menu-second-block">
            <div className="folders">Folders</div>
            <div className="folders">Home</div>
            <div className="folders">Calendar</div>
          </div>
          <div className="horison-menu-third-block">
            <div className="sort">
              <img src={sort} alt="sort image" />
              sort by
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.isModalOpened && (
          <NewNoteModal
            isOpened={this.state.isModalOpened}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            addItem={this.props.addItem}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./NewNoteModal.css";

export default class NewNoteModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      text: "",
      isActive: this.props.isOpened
    };
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isActive) {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="new-note-modal">
            <div className="modal-title">
              <p>New note</p>
              <div
                className="delete-btn"
                onClick={() => this.props.closeModal()}
              >
                <svg
                  width="16"
                  height="16"
                  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="#FF4D4D" />
                  <path
                    d="M5.17163 5.17163L10.8285 10.8285"
                    stroke="white"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                  />
                  <path
                    d="M10.8285 5.17163L5.17164 10.8285"
                    stroke="white"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="title"
                className="new-note-title"
              />
              <textarea
                type="textarea"
                placeholder="note text"
                rows="10"
                cols="12"
              ></textarea>
              <button
                className="btn-add"
                type="submit"
                onClick={() => this.props.addItem("hello", "world")}
              >
                add
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил некоторые моменты, оформление и стилия я удалял чтобы у меня на компьютере работало. Вся логика работает. Прилагаю работяющий код ниже. Вот что исправил:

1)В `App` классе:    удалил `modal` из состояния    `randomId` должно  быть функцией `addItem, deleteItem` - рефактор 2)`NoteBoard`:   состояние удалил, оно приходит из пропс 3)NoteItem - немного упростил HTML, вроде нет ошибок 4)HorizontalMenu - упростил разметку чтобы у меня работало 5)NewNoteModal переписал на хуках, давно с классами не работал, использование HTML формы тоже древняя тема. Добавил логику  чтобы всё работало.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: [
        {
          id: "fghsf",
          completed: false,
          title: "Hello World",
          text:
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took",
        },
        {
          id: "adfgd",
          completed: false,
          title: "toggle JavaScript",
          text:
            "The toggle() method of the DOMTokenList interface removes a given token from the list and returns false. If token doesn't exist it's added and the function returns true.",
        },
        {
          id: "asdsa",
          completed: false,
          title: "Fetch API",
          text:
            "The Fetch API provides a JavaScript interface for accessing and manipulating parts of the HTTP pipeline, such as requests and responses. It also provides a global fetch() method that provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network.",
        },
        {
          id: "12312sasda",
          completed: false,
          title: "Single-page application (SPA)",
          text:
            "A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or website that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current web page with new data from the web server, instead of the default method of the browser loading entire new pages.",
        },
      ],
    };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
  }
  getRandomId = () => `f${(~~(Math.random() * 1e8)).toString(16)}`;

  addItem(title, text) {
    const newItem = {
      id: this.getRandomId(),
      completed: false,
      title,
      text,
    };

    this.setState(({ todos }) => {
      const newArr = [...todos, newItem];
      return {
        todos: newArr,
      };
    });
  }

  deleteItem(id) {
    this.setState(({ todos }) => ({
      todos: todos.filter((item) => item.id !== id),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.todos);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          Menu
          <div className="notes-block-container">
            SearchPanel
            <HorizontalMenu addItem={this.addItem} />
            <NoteBoard todos={todos} onDelete={this.deleteItem} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class NoteBoard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todos } = this.props;
    const { onDelete } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="noteBoard-container">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <NoteItem
            todo={todo}
            key={todo.id}
            onDelete={() => onDelete(todo.id)}
            id={todo.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class NoteItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { todo, onDelete } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="note-item">
        <div className="note-title">{todo.title}</div>
        <p className="note-text">{todo.text}</p>
        <button onClick={onDelete}>delete me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalOpened: false,
    };
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpened: true,
    });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({
      isModalOpened: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="horison-menu">
        HorizontalMenu
        <button className="new-note" onClick={() => this.openModal()}>
          new note
        </button>
        {this.state.isModalOpened && (
          <NewNoteModal
            isOpened={this.state.isModalOpened}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            addItem={this.props.addItem}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const NewNoteModal = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div className="new-note-modal">
      <div className="modal-title">
        <p>New note</p>
        <button className="delete-btn" onClick={() => this.props.closeModal()}>
          <svg
        width="16"
        height="16"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8" fill="#FF4D4D" />
        <path
          d="M5.17163 5.17163L10.8285 10.8285"
          stroke="white"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
        <path
          d="M10.8285 5.17163L5.17164 10.8285"
          stroke="white"
          strokeWidth="2"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
        />
      </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={({ target }) => setTitle(target.value)}
        />
        <textarea
          type="text"
          placeholder="note text"
          value={text}
          rows="10"
          cols="12"
          onChange={({ target }) => setText(target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className="btn-add"
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => {
            props.addItem(title, text);
            props.closeModal();
          }}
        >
          add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал как вы сказали, все заработало, очень вам благодарен!)

Comment: спасибо, поставь если не сложно стрелку вверх/лайк моему ответу я буду тоже благодарен )

Comment: Поставил сразу, у меня просто низкий уровень, если ниже 15-го учитывает оценку но не отображает:(